# Javascript, one check box checked = location.html, 2 checkbox checked = anotherlocation.html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a problem with a form I am trying to create in html and javascript

firstly I would like to have multiple check boxes

if one is checked, onsubmit the user is taken to one url

if two boxes are checked, onsubmit the user is taken to another url etc..

Is this possible and if so what would the javascript or jquery be???????

Comment: Please post your code - or whatever your have attempted. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions

Comment: What have you got so far in terms of code? Are you having problems running code on submit? Is it the choosing which page to send to, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Some code would be good because I have no idea what mechanism you're using to submit your form, but the solution would most likely involve something like this:

```
   switch ($('form input:checkbox:checked').length) 
    {
    case 1:
    window.location.href = url1;
    break;
    case 2:
    window.location.href = url2;
    break;
    //etc
    default:
    }
```

**EDIT**: Ok I have to give some credit to Valentin so let's combine solutions.

```
    var $myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');

    $('#myForm input:checkbox').on('change', function(event){
        switch ($('#myForm input:checkbox:checked').length) 
        {
        case 1:
        $myForm.action = url1;
        break;
        case 2:
        $myForm.action = url2;
        break;
        //etc
        default:
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you could make use of the `onCheck` and `onUnCheck` of the checkboxes and have them modify the action-attribute of your form to whatever page the user should be taken.

So your HTML could be:

```
<form method="post" action="whateverpage.php" id="myform">
<input type="checkbox" id="check0"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="check1"/> 
<input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
</form>
```

And your javascript:

```
yourform=document.getElementById("myform");
checkbox0=document.getElementById("check0");
checkbox1=document.getElementById("check1");

checkbox0.onCheck=function(){
  if(checkbox1.checked==true){
    yourform.action="bothchecked.php";
  }else{
    yourform.action="firstchecked.php";
  }
}
checkbox1.onCheck=function(){
  if(checkbox0.checked==true){
    yourform.action="bothchecked.php";
  }else{
    yourform.action="secondchecked.php";
  }
}
checkbox1.onUnCheck=function(){
  if(checkbox0.checked==true){
    yourform.action="firstchecked.php";
  }else{
    yourform.action="nonechecked.php";
  }
}
checkbox0.onUnCheck=function(){
  if(checkbox1.checked==true){
    yourform.action="secondchecked.php";
  }else{
    yourform.action="nonechecked.php";
  }
}
```

Of course you can use `yourform.setAttribute("action","page.php");` alternatively.